# Symfony2 collection order by priority switch places

Tags: symfony, doctrine, arraycollection

I want to make a priority mechanic for a Entity, by default I'll sort everything by priority (not by Id), I'd like for priority to be set on persist (with the Objects Id) so I can switch the order of items on the list and always be pushed as the last one.

What's the best method to assign the priority on the object? using lifecycle callbacks on persist? or is there a quicker method?

TL;DR; 
Need variable that is set like id of an object just allows switching 2 elements so I can move one up the list.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you wrote correctly, you might want to research the "sortable" doctrine behaviour:

https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/sortable.md